# Полное имя вызывающего процесса в модуле ядра linux

Tags: c++, linux, процесс, ядро

Есть модуль, осуществляющий хук некоторых системных вызовов, необходимо определить полный путь к образу процесса, который осуществил системный вызов.

Сейчас получаю

```
current->pid
```

после чего делаю

```
sys_readlink((char*)link, buf, bufsize);
```

от

```
/proc/#PID#/exe
```

получая почти всегда полный путь, но для некоторых процессов (например, chrome иногда) вместо полного пути возвращается только имя процесса.

Есть ли другой способ определить полный путь к образу вызывающего процесса ?

Comment: И безотносительно к модулям ядра вопрос интересный. 

Насколько я понимаю, \*nix-ы полный (да и неполный) путь к файлу существует (как реальность), только в момент конкретного системного вызова. 

Для системы файл это i-node. Путей к нему может быть несколько (а в данный момент и вообще уже ни одного (?) (ну, в этом я не уверен, пройдет ли `unlink()` для исполняющегося в этот момент файла?)).

Простого способа найти путь к иноду не вижу.

Я понимаю, что Вы читаете символьный линк, в котором хотите обнаружить путь, а его там иногда нет, т.е. комментарий не совсем в тему.

Comment: Не берусь утверждать, но unlink() к образу действующего процесса скорее всего не пройдет - области памяти, которая помечена как исполняемая, должно быть задано соответствующее отображение на файловую систему (тот самый образ процесса), впрочем это достаточно просто проверить.

Comment: Для файла загрузочного модуля исполняющейся программы unlink(), rename() (rm, mv) работают, touch тоже, а вот **запись** в этот файл не разрешается

    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ cat >a.out 
    bash: a.out: Текстовый файл занят

Собственно чего это я в своем предыдущем комментарии засомневался в этом ? 

Очевидно ведь, что изменения в каталоге не связаны с изменениями самого файла.

P.S.

"Текстовый файл занят" - ну не дурацкий ли  перевод "text file busy" ?
Где они таких "русификаторов" набрали ?

Answer (score 3):

Есть такая функция  [proc_pid_cmdline](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.2/fs/proc/base.c#L206). Я уверен, что либо она сама, либо ее содержимое будет полезно. Однако надо заметить, что получение полного имени процесса не всегда возможно. Скорее всего это врядли получится в контексте обработчика прерывания.

Comment: Кирилл, а это не то же самое, что прочитать файл /proc/PID/cmdline ?

Comment: Зависит от того, что в конкретный момент вам доступнее и удобнее. Результат, очевидно, будет один и тот же.

Comment: Да, результат, естественно тот же что и при чтении /proc/PID/cmdline. Дело в том, что он далеко не всегда содержит именно путь к исполняемому образу.

За функцию спасибо, поизучаю, возможно что-то полезное для себя вытащу.